# Can I get the column index in -tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Can I get the current column index from the datasource method:

```
-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can search for the given NSTableColumn in the NSTableView columns...

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    NSUInteger index = [[aTableView tableColumns] indexOfObject:aTableColumn];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will never understand why Apple makes the simplest things so unintuitive! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: the method is now called indexOfObject

Comment: You should rather rely on the tableComumn.identifier to identify a column. This is impervious to table layout changes by the user and makes it safer for future development where you dont need to keep table column layout respective to your data model.

Answer (score 0):

If someone searches for such implementation in Swift, here is how you can do that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    if let tableColumn = tableColumn,
       let index = tableView.tableColumns.firstIndex(of: tableColumn) {
        // Do your things with index
    }
    return nil // or return your object
}
```